# RadListView combined Swipe & Click (Press)

Tags: nativescript

I work with `RadListView`.

There is way to combien `Click` and `Swipe` actions ? if I set `swipeActions="true"` and `selectionBehavior="Press"` the `Press` event will be fired first .. The problem is I use the Press event to navigate and the navigation start on swiping !

I think there is way to achieve this on checking if swipe being to start, then disable Press event .. and when `itemSwipeProgressEnded` event is fired re bind `Press` event !!

But I hop there is way more cool to achieve to same result ?

```xml
<lv:RadListView 
            id="listView" 
            items="{{ dataItems }}" 
            row="1" 
            selectionBehavior="Press" 
            itemSelecting="{{ itemSelected }}"
            itemSwipeProgressEnded="onSwipeCellFinished"
            itemSwipeProgressStarted="onSwipeCellStarted" 
            itemSwipeProgressChanged="onCellSwiping" 
            multipleSelection="false"
            swipeActions="true">
```

Comment: You may bypass navigate event if swipe is already started, toggle a variable value upon swipe start and end, check if swipe is active before navigation.

Comment: Thanks for response,
The problem is the data come from `RadListView` is not really exact ! and `itemSwipeProgressStarted` is fired when swipe start from `0` to and `itemSwipeProgressEnded`  `x` or `-x'

Comment: Other think is to use this function : 
```ts
private isSwipeOpend(args: SwipeActionsEventData): boolean {
        const leftDimensions = View.measureChild(
                <View>leftItem.parent,
                leftItem,
                layout.makeMeasureSpec(Math.abs(args.data.x), layout.EXACTLY),
                layout.makeMeasureSpec(mainView.getMeasuredHeight(), layout.EXACTLY));
        console.log(leftDimensions)
        return leftDimensions.measuredWidth !== 0;
    }
```

At this stage I try to fin other way !